# Fantasy Font Loading differently in ie

Tags: html, css, cross-platform

I am using default Font-Family as "Fantasy"(default font), i want it to look like as it is showing in chrome, but ie is rendering it Completely Differently

Here is it on Js Fiddle Loading differently in IE and Chrome

```
p{font-family: fantasy;}
```

[JS Fidldle Created](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7mQD/16/)

Thanks

Comment: Fonts like `fantasy` and `cursive` etc. are just what the user declares them to be. I'm not sure you can actually set them in IE though. Or in Chrome, to be honest. But you can in Firefox!

Comment: then what's the work around of it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? That IE uses the same font as Chrome? Then find out which font Chrome uses, and set that font explicitly in the CSS. `p {font-family: 'WhatTheFont', fantasy;}`

Comment: Chrome only shows fantasy name nothing other than that and ie is not rendering it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used

```
font-family:Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
```

to get the fantasy font in chrome in all browsers..

Answer (score 1):

Use this it works perfect..

```
font-family:Papyrus,fantasy;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tahoma and Fantasy are Almost Similar Rendering Arabic so i used Tahome Instead because it renders same in ie and chrome